# Is it possible to use SObject Formula fields to get arbitrary values stored in some other SObject?

Tags: custom-field, sobject, formula-field, relationships

Let's say I have some SObject (myCode__c) with three string values (e.g. key1__c, key2__c, and code__c).  The combination of key1__c and key2__c should be unique.

Let's say I have a second SObject (myObject__c) which includes two picklists (e.g. category1__c and category2__c).

Values for myObject__r.category1__c correspond to myCode__r.key1__c and values for myObject__r.category2__c correspond with myCode__r.key2__c.

Is it possible to have a formula field on myObject__c which gives a value for myCode__r.code__c, as determined in accord with each objects other two fields?

(If so, how?)

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for is called "VLOOKUP" but is only available in validation rules.

If you want to learn more about VLOOPUPs: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gyFzAAI

Comment: Cheers for the response.  I don't suppose you'd be able to elaborate why it is only available for validation (not that understanding such would help anyway).  :-/

Comment: @BrianKessler Because salesforce doesn't allow it. You'll ultimately need a trigger to accomplish your goals.